# Retrieving values from a map for a filtered set of keys

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala programming and am looking for a way to retrieve a list of values from a map for a filtered set of keys in another map.

Ex- 
filter =[k1,k2,k3]
inputMap=[k1->1, k1->2, k2->6, k2->7, k2->9, k3->5, k10->66, k4->45]

outputMap = [k1->(1,2),k2->(6,7,9),k3->(5)]

Thanks in advance!
-Nancy

Comment: If I have understood your question properly, keys in maps are unique - meaning you don't use the same key more than once in a map - are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: perhaps you want your inputMap to look like this? `Map("k1" -> (1,2), "k2" -> (6, 7, 9), "k3" -> 5, "k10" -> 66, "k4" -> 45)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of 'inputMap' looks more like list of key-value pairs, because map cannot contain duplicate keys.
So:

```
val list = List("k1"->1, "k1"->2, "k2"->6, "k2"->7, "k2"->9, "k3"->5, "k10"->66, "k4"->45)
val f = Set("k1", "k2", "k3")  //filter
```

First filter only required keys:

```
scala>val filtered = list.filter {case (k,v)=>f(k)}
filtered: List[(String, Int)] = List((k1,1), (k1,2), (k2,6), (k2,7), (k2,9), (k3,5))
```

Next grouping by key:

```
scala>val grouped = filtered.groupBy(_._1)
grouped: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, Int)]] = Map(k2 -> List((k2,6), (k2,7), (k2,9)), k1 -> List((k1,1), (k1,2)), k3 -> List((k3,5)))
```

Now convert to desired format:

```
val outputMap = grouped.map {case (k,v)=>k->v.map{case (ki,vi) => vi}}
outputMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(k2 -> List(6, 7, 9), k1 -> List(1, 2), k3 -> List(5))
```

Comment: Thanks Nyavro. I'm trying to do what you've suggested. However i'm getting an error when i try filter.  val filtered = nodeFollowersList.filter {case (k,v)=>filteredNodesSet(k)}  Error: "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[INFO]  found   : (T1, T2)
[INFO]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]"

Comment: nodeFollowersList is a List of tuples <node,link> and filteredNodesSet is a set of nodes

Comment: val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://moonshot-ha-nameservice" + args(0))
 val splitNodes = lines.map(line => line.split("\t"))
 val nodeFollowers = splitNodes.map(x => (x(0).toString,x(1).toString))
 val nodeFollowersList = List(nodeFollowers)
 val filteredLines = sc.textFile("hdfs://moonshot-ha-nameservice" + args(1))
 val persistedFilteredlines=filteredLines.persist() 
 val splitFilteredNodes=persistedFilteredlines.map(line => line.split(","))
 val extractFilteredNodes=splitFilteredNodes.map(line => (line(0).substring(1, line(0).length)).toString)
 val filteredNodesSet =Set(extractFilteredNodes)

Comment: In code of your last comment you have several issues. You're constructing List and Set wrongly. Set and List does not accept another collection as argument to it's apply method. so Set(extractFilteredNodes) means 'create set of list'.

Comment: I would advice to write explicitly types of val-s. And don't try to write whole program at once. Go with small steps, make one line work, then another and so on. Good luck!